# How to edit a preference from the code

Tags: java, android, checkbox, set, preferences

I would like to edit an android preference (checkBox preference) depending on the conditions. When I open the preferences activity I choose some option and it should affect other option (it should change value of other preference.

Example:

1. I change the vehicle type {motorbike, car}.
2. Automatically tire number should change {2, 4} //motorbike can have 2 or 4 wheels (quad) but car cant have 2).
   This is just an example to let you imagine what I want to do.

How can I do that?

I know that I can get the preference value, but how can I set it from the code?